# What is the reason of this Google OAuth2 login error

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, gmail, token

I'm working with a desktop application, trying to develop a function to allow application users sending out emails using their GMAIL account.

I've created client ID, secret and set up consent screen for my application. The token was got successfully. But when I try to login using this token, the following error happens:

```
SmtpCmdResp: 334
Failed to login using XOAUTH2 method
```

The complete mailing log is like the following:

```
ChilkatLog:
  SendEmail:
    DllDate: Sep 28 2020
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.84
    UnlockPrefix: Auto unlock for 30-day trial
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: ActiveX
    VerboseLogging: 0
    Component successfully unlocked using trial key
    sendEmailInner:
      renderToMime_pt1:
        createEmailForSending:
          Auto-generating Message-ID
        --createEmailForSending
      --renderToMime_pt1
      sendMimeInner:
        ensureSmtpSession:
          ensureSmtpConnection:
            smtpParams:
              SmtpHost: smtp.gmail.com
              SmtpPort: 587
              SmtpUsername: xxxxx@gmail.com
              SmtpSsl: 0
              StartTLS: 1
            --smtpParams
            smtpConnect:
              smtpHostname: smtp.gmail.com
              smtpPort: 587
              connectionIsReady:
                Need new SMTP connection
              --connectionIsReady
              smtpSocketConnect:
                socketOptions:
                  SO_SNDBUF: 262144
                  SO_RCVBUF: 4194304
                  TCP_NODELAY: 1
                  SO_KEEPALIVE: 1
                --socketOptions
              --smtpSocketConnect
              smtpGreeting:
                readSmtpResponse:
                  SmtpCmdResp: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP z20sm6231415qtb.31 - gsmtp
                --readSmtpResponse
              --smtpGreeting
              startTLS:
                sendCmdToSmtp:
                  SmtpCmdSent: EHLO xxxxxxxxx<CRLF>
                --sendCmdToSmtp
                readSmtpResponse:
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [198.52.156.138]
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-SIZE 35882577
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-8BITMIME
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-STARTTLS
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-PIPELINING
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-CHUNKING
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250 SMTPUTF8
                --readSmtpResponse
                sendCmdToSmtp:
                  SmtpCmdSent: STARTTLS<CRLF>
                --sendCmdToSmtp
                readSmtpResponse:
                  SmtpCmdResp: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
                --readSmtpResponse
                TLS connection established.
              --startTLS
              ehloCommand:
                sendCmdToSmtp:
                  SmtpCmdSent: EHLO xxxxxxxxx<CRLF>
                --sendCmdToSmtp
                readSmtpResponse:
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [198.52.156.138]
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-SIZE 35882577
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-8BITMIME
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-PIPELINING
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250-CHUNKING
                  SmtpCmdResp: 250 SMTPUTF8
                --readSmtpResponse
              --ehloCommand
            --smtpConnect
          --ensureSmtpConnection
          ensureSmtpAuthenticated:
            smtpAuthenticate:
              smtp_host: smtp.gmail.com
              smtp_port: 587
              smtp_user: xxxxx@gmail.com
              smtpAuthenticate:
                login_method: XOAUTH2
                auth_xoauth2:
                  username: xxxxx@gmail.com
                  sendCmdToSmtp:
                    SmtpCmdSent: {PasswordOrCredentials}
                  --sendCmdToSmtp
                  readSmtpResponse:
                    SmtpCmdResp: 334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==
                  --readSmtpResponse
                --auth_xoauth2
                Failed to login using XOAUTH2 method
              --smtpAuthenticate
              ConnectionType: SSL/TLS
            --smtpAuthenticate
          --ensureSmtpAuthenticated
        --ensureSmtpSession
      --sendMimeInner
    --sendEmailInner
    Failed.
  --SendEmail
--ChilkatLog
```

I was using PoweBuilder as the development language and this log is from a third party OCX control named Chilkat. Note that I've replaced the computer name and my testing Gmail account user name with "x". Other parts are kept original. The token was saved to a file located at local hard drive and then got read and used.

Does any one know if the login failure is because of my application is not validated by Google yet? Or it just indicates that the token was not valid, or something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Reason was found. It's because of the scope defined when trying to get the token did not include "https://mail.google.com".

The clue is in the line of 334 response code. Decoding the base64 string after "SmtpCmdResp: 334", it is actually {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}.

I then search for this string in Google and found out that this means the scope of "https://mail.google.com" was not included when trying to get the token. When I include this scope in my PowerBuilder code, I could send out email successfully.

This makes me feel bad. The scope "https://mail.google.com/" means that user need to consent all the permissions about his/her Gmail account to the application. But what the application needs was just to represent the user to login to Gmail SMTP Server and send out email(s) on his/her behalf. The application does not need to have access to anything else like what email(s) has been sent out, or who's in the address book, or what's in the inbox. To tell the truth, I was thinking of clicking "No" when I test out this function and the consent page tells me that I need permit everything.